# php html remove line break from meta description tag

Tags: php, line-breaks, html

I am printing page content from a MYSQL db in PHP. I have a text field in db called $row['description']

When storing users input into db I only use mysql_real_escape_string() so I do not edit html

Problem is I use this field from db as the html pages meta description tag. So if user inserted line breaks in description they cause a line break in the source code of the page within the meta description tag. I tried to remove the line break by using a loop to skip an br formats. I use the nl2br to convert to br.

```
$desc_array=(explode(" ", $row['description']));
for($i=0; $i < 17;$i++){
    if(nl2br($desc_array[$i])=="<br />" || nl2br($desc_array[$i])=="<br/>"){
        $i++;
    }
```

I checked my SQL file and the line breaks appear as

```
\r\n\r\n
```

I have tried to check for this format too like

```
 $desc_array[$i])=="\r\n\r\n"
 $desc_array[$i])=="\r\n"
 $desc_array[$i])=="\n"
 $desc_array[$i])=="\r"
```

but still line break gets printed in description tag. Any ideas?

Comment: Try doing `var_dump($desc_array)` after you do the explode. It'll show exactly what each element becomes, and how long it is (string length). That'll give you an idea of what hidden characters are in there.

Comment: Tried var_dump() and it appears to not show any characters for line breaks. Output is this from where there should be a line break ([14]=> string(17) "balcony. There" [15]=> string(2) "is") Note there should be line break between 'balcony.' and 'There' however this shows its just part of same string?

Comment: view the page source - HTML view in browsers doesn't honor text line break characters and treats them as invisible or a space character.

Comment: Well I suppose it does not matter if theres a line break in description tag google does not include it in search results and it does not affect rankings does it?

Comment: You'd probably be better off just replacing them with something else, as in webarto's answer below.

Answer (score 5):

```
$string = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), array('', ''), $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will tell you my opinion as I encountered this sitioation over and over.

Sometimes trimming out `\r\n`, `\n` helps, sometimes not.
In few cases i found out that i have to remove like so:

```
<?php
$desc = "This
is a description";
// this is just a line break [enter]
$newDesc = str_replace(" 
", " ", $desc); // witch outputs This is a description
?>
```

I never had the curiosity to find out why it doesn't want \r\n or \n, maybe i'll foind out now :)

Comment: There is a chance you will still have `\r` if you replace `\r\n` and then `\n` :)